# Historical eras or Time periods or Historical periods

Tags: word-choice

> Many ethnic groups had migrated into Vietnamese territory at different ***historical eras***: some had come thousands of years ago which is fairly early and some had come several hundred years ago.

I don't know which phrase to use here?

I feel like "historical" and "era" usually go together; "time" and "period" go together. But I think historical eras refer to a decided way of classifying time periods whereas, in this sentence, the sense I'm leaning towards is a bit vague and general.

Also, "time periods", is it enough to describe the periods in the past already? or do I need to add something here?

If I combine them and use "historical periods", will it still sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ethnic groups had migrated into Vietnamese territory at different times in their  history: some had come thousands of years ago which is fairly early and some had come several hundred years ago.

This is basically editing.

Comment: Why do we need any of the *hads*? Many ethnic groups *migrated* into Vietnamese territory at different times in their history: some *came* thousands of years ago, fairly early, and some several hundred years ago.

Comment: Thank you. Both of you are a great help.

Comment: @YosefBaskin For emphasis. Also, in this case, it reads better.